# Publish my design work to portofolio but hide client's identity

Tags: print-design

I have a question that has been stuck in my head for a quite a long time. Let's say, I designed a business card for my client and would like to publish the design to my portfolio. Because the business card has my client's identity (name, phone number, email, etc), is it okay if I publish the design while hiding my client's identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Just use a dummy name and contact info. The actual name, title, phone, etc., are *not* important. It's the type usage and placement which will convey the overall design.

> Jonathan Deux
>   Chief Executive Officer
>   555.555.5555
>   jon@example.com
>   111 Main Street
>   Anytown, US 00000
>   www.example.com

That being posted..... if there's a logo, well, you can't really "hide" the identity of a logo. And removing a logo from something like a business card can cause the design to *completely* fall apart.

So, leave the branding, but replace any personal information or contact information.

[ref](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/33715/3270)

Comment: You can "blur-mask" relevant data and leave the original, you can greek the content (better option) and in many cases, if the client's business is well known, well regarded, and/or the branding and corporate identity you have done for that client is well regarded, *and* the client is consulted and approves, you can in fact use the original content with their info, and thus benefit from the sterling work you've already accomplished.